# HTML JS CSS Value not showing in Column Cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit new to technology.

i"m trying to build a dashboard. But when I pass the attribute id to the cards. it's not displaying the values.

Sometimes I'm only getting value for the 1st card only. do I have to add additional div? or any other ways?

how to resolve these?.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
 fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/225')
 .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
 .then(function(data) {
  let population = data.location.country_population;
  let update = data.location.last_updated;
  let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed;
  let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths;

  document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = population.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = update.substr(0, 10);
  document.getElementById('cases').innerHTML = confirmedCases.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('deaths').innerHTML = deaths.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = ((Number(deaths)/Number(confirmedCases))*100).toLocaleString("en", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}) + "%";




 })
 .catch(function() {
  console.log("error");
 })
 setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>* {box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        
         h1{
            font-size: smaller;
        }

        /* Float four columns side by side */
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }

        /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
        .row {
            margin: 0 -5px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Responsive columns */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
        }

        /* Style the counter cards */
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Responsive Column Cards</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 1</h3>

                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="population"></h1>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 2</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="cases"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 3</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="deaths"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 4</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="percent"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: value missing]

above is how I'm getting. I need to display the values in the red boxed areas.

Answer (score 0):

This happend because this line

`document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = update.substr(0, 10);`

you don't have an element with the id `update`. And JS crash in that line. You need to comment that line or add a validator to check if that element exist.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
 fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/225')
 .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
 .then(function(data) {
  let population = data.location.country_population;
  let update = data.location.last_updated;
  let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed;
  let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths;

  document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = population.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('cases').innerHTML = confirmedCases.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('deaths').innerHTML = deaths.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = ((Number(deaths)/Number(confirmedCases))*100).toLocaleString("en", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}) + "%";




 })
 .catch(function() {
  console.log("error");
 })
 setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        
         h1{
            font-size: smaller;
        }

        /* Float four columns side by side */
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }

        /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
        .row {
            margin: 0 -5px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Responsive columns */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
        }

        /* Style the counter cards */
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Responsive Column Cards</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 1</h3>

                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="population"></h1>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 2</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="cases"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 3</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="deaths"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Card 4</h3>
                <h4>Cases</h4>
                <h1 id="percent"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an HTML block. Add this to your HTML below the population data:

```
<div class="column">
   <div class="card">
     <h3>Card</h3>
     <h4>Cases</h4>
     <h1 id="update"></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Just a quick tips, you can put your CSS styles in an external file and the access it so that your HTML file won't get messy. Create a new file (style.css) and copy all your CSS and paste into the style.css. Then add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` to the head of HTML.